# pass data from client side to server before page_load executes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pageload

A button on html page redirect to aspx page with `window.open()` command.
There are certain data on the html page which i want on server-side of the aspx page before `page_load` executes.

following is my code on the html page which redirects to the aspx page

```
var win = window.open('mypage.aspx','_self');
win.args=this.Args;
```

following is my code on aspx page which tries to catch the data passed from the html page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

 var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function () {
            if (document.readyState === "loading") {
                $('#hdnArgs').val(window.args);
                clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
            }
        }, 100);

</script>

<input type='hidden' id='hdnArgs' runat='server'/>
```

Following is the code on the aspx.cs file which tries to read the hidden variable's value which has been set from the data of the html page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    string data = hdnArgs.value; //this is always null
}
```

But what I get is always 'null'.

The `readyStateCheckInterval` sets the hidden variable value after the `page_load` event is completed.

I want the value of hidden variable before `page_load`.
How can I get that?

Comment: Is your Jquery returning proper value for that HiddenField ?

Comment: Okay. Now if you want to play with it before `Page_Load`, you can try it in the `Page_Init` method which runs before PageLoad. Not sure if that would work, you can give it a try.

Comment: Cant access the 'Window' variable server side. It has to be on client side and store value in some literal or hidden variable to access it on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its not possible to set value of any control before page life cycle finish.

let me explain you..
You try to set value on `hdnArgs`  but In Page lifecycle control only generate and send it to browser only after finish `Page_init,Page_Load,Page_Load_Complete`
All those methods..

So,When you try set `args` value to hdnArgs using `$('#hdnArgs').val(window.args);` Page_load event already completed..

**Solution**

I think you need to pass value as a QueryString to get Value in `Page_load`

```
var win = window.open('mypage.aspx?Args='+this.Args,'_self');
```

and In ASPX page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, eventargs e)
{
string data = Request.QueryString["Args"];
}
```

Also you can send data using Page Postback if you have large data.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm:

- hdnArgs is on the starting page
- starting page opens a new page in a window
- when that page is opening (but not complete, which will hopefully happen when you happen to look at it at 100ms intervals... it won't if it's quicker than that), input#hdnArgs is updated to the a value from the opened page
- The Page_Load is on the starting page
- You want the start page Page_Load to get a value from the popup

You'll need to review the lifecycle of asp.net pages, eg: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

By the time the start page even thinks about processing any javascript, the Page_Load of the startup page is long gone.

Perhaps, in the Page_Load, you could load the new page directly eg with

```
var content = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(contentUrl);
```

and parsing it for the #hvnArgs

Comment: hdnArgs and page_load is on target page. not on source page

Comment: That's why I added the 'to confirm', because this "following is my code on aspx page" states otherwise.  Either way, `Page_Load` occurs before the page is sent to the browser, therefore before any client script runs. If you want values passed to your popup's Page_Load, simple pass them on the URL `window.open('mypage.aspx?args=xxx'...`